# How to perform sonar analysis only for one module at once using gradle or maven?

Tags: java, gradle, sonarqube, continuous-integration

Given gradle project structure like below

```
parent
- moduleA
- moduleB
```

It's possible to perform sonar analysis using gradle plugin 'org.sonarqube' for entire project structure with command

```
gradle sonarqube
```

When I try to perform analysis only for moduleA or moduleB then an exception appears in SonarQube build task:

```
org.sonar.api.utils.MessageException: Validation of project failed:
  o Component (uuid=XXX, key=parent:moduleA) is not a project
  o The project "parent:moduleA" is already defined in SonarQube but as a module of project "parent". If you really want to stop directly analysing project "parent", please first delete it from SonarQube and then relaunch the analysis of project "parent:moduleA".
```

parent/build.gradle Sonar configuration:

```
sonarqube {
    properties {
        ...
        property "sonar.projectKey", "parent"
    }
}
```

parent/moduleA/build.gradle Sonar configuration

```
sonarqube {
    properties {
        ...
        property "sonar.projectKey", "parent:moduleA"
    }
}
```

Did I miss something or maybe it is impossible to analyze specified module of the project?

Comment: Could you share the relevant part of your build file(s) ?

Comment: added sonarqube plugin config (wihtout credentials and host address)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do a partial analysis of a SonarQube project.

Either you analyze the entire project every times. Or you analyze each Gradle module as a separate SonarQube project in the first place.